# Как переписать данный код для защиты от sql инъекций?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, sql-injection

Я совсем недавно начал изучать php и в процессе пишу подобие блога. В процессе узнал об опасности sql инъекций. Гуглил об этом, но результаты немного не под мой случай, не смог разобраться. Как переписать этот код чтобы защититься от sql инъекций?

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $config['title'];?></title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- CSS -->
<?php include('css/style.сss'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

<div class="container mt-2" id="wrapper">
<div class="row title-article">
    <div class="col-2 p-2">
        <h5>Новейшее</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">

    </div>
    <div class="col-2 title-part p-2">
        <a href="articles.php"><h5>Все статьи</h5></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2" >
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-12">

        <?php
        $articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");//вывод на страницу последних 10 добавленных статей ?>
            <?php while($art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles))
                {
                ?>
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="col-12 article all-art mb-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 img-article" >
                        <img src="static/images/<?php echo $art['image']?>" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 article-content">
                        <h4><a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $art['id'];?>"><?php echo $art['title'];?></a></h4>
                        <?php 
                      $art_cat = false;
                      foreach($categories as $cat) {
                        if($cat['id'] == $art['categorie_id']){
                          $art_cat = $cat;
                          break;
                        }
                      }
                    ?>
                        <small>Категория: <?php echo $art_cat['title'];?></small>
                        <p><?php echo mb_substr(strip_tags($art['text']), 0, 100, 'utf-8') . '...';?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>

    <?php include('includes/sidebar.php'); ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

И посоветуйте соответствующий материал для новичка.
Заранее спасибо.
Вот страница article.php

```
<?php $article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE 
`id` = " . (int) $_GET['id']);
if(mysqli_num_rows($article)<=0)
{
?>
<div class="container mt-2" id="wrapper">
<div class="row title-article">
<div class="col-6 p-2">
        <h5>Запрашиваемая вами статья не существует!</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-2 title-part p-2">
        <a href=""><h5>Все статьи</h5></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }
else{
    $art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($article);
  mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE `articles` SET `views` = `views` + 1 
WHERE `id` = " . (int) $art['id']); ?>
  <div class="row mt-2" >
    <div class="container mt-2" id="wrapper">
<div class="row title-article">
    <div class="col-6 p-2">
        <h5><?php echo $art['title']; ?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-2 title-part p-2">
        <a href="articles.php"><h5>Все статьи</h5></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2" >
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-12 article-block">
        <img src="static/images/<?php echo $art['image']; ?>" alt="">
        <p><?php echo $art['text'];?></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Здесь нет sql-инъекций

Comment: Какие тут sql-инъекции? Вы не передаете входные данные в запрос

Comment: "sql-инъекций" - это нарушение, когда внутрь sql кода вставляется строковое значение переменной полученое из-вне (как простой метод создать sql). Тут такого нету. Почитайте тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0 и на хабре https://habr.com/post/130826/

Comment: обработать `$art['id']` надо в файле `arcticle.php` а не тут. а вернее `$_GET['id']`